# How are strings stored as bytes in databases?

Tags: database, mongodb, serialization, redis, deserialization

This question may be a little vague, but let me try to explain it clearly. I have been reading a database related tutorial, and it mentioned tables are serialized to bytes to be persisted on the disk. When we deserialize them, we can locate each column based on the size of its type.

For example, we have a table:

```
---------------------------------------------------
| id (unsigned int 8) | timestamp (signed int 32) |
---------------------------------------------------
|      Some Id        |        Some time          |  
---------------------------------------------------
```

When we are deserializing a byte array loaded from a file, we know the first 8 bits are the `id`, and the following 32 bits are the `timestamp`.

But the tutorial never mentioned how `strings` are handled in databases. They are not specific to a limited size, like 32 bits, and they are not predictable the size wise (there can always be a long long String, who knows). So how exactly does databases handle strings?

I know in RDBMS, you need to specify the size of the string as `Varchar(45)` for example, then it becomes easier. But what about dbs like MongoDB or Redis, which does not require a specification for string sizes, do they just assume it to be a specific length and increase the size once a longer one comes in?

That is basically my vague non-specific question, hope someone can give me some ideas on this. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MongoDB, documents are serialized as BSON (Binary JSON-like objects). See [BSON spec](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html) for more details regarding the datatypes for each type.

For string type, it is stored as:

```
<unsigned32 strsizewithnull><cstring>
```

From [this line in the MongoDB source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/r4.2.0/src/mongo/bson/bsonobj.h#L83).

So a string field is stored with its length (including the null terminator) in the BSON object. The string itself is UTF-8 encoded as per BSON spec, so it can be encoded using a variable amount of bytes per symbol. Together with other fields that makes up a document, they are compressed using [Snappy by default](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#compression). This compressed representation is the one persisted to disk.

WiredTiger is a no-overwrite storage engine. If that document is updated, WiredTiger creates a new document and updates the internal pointer to the new one, and mark the old document as "space available for reuse".